# isArray check and inferred type never in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do a simple array check in TypeScript, but apparently what it does is infer that if it's not an array (which actually accepts type `any` as a parameter), then it must be of type `never`. I got curious about how this works in TypeScript. What is the correct way to handle this inference with `isArray` specifically?

The code is:

```
if (Array.isArray(response)) {
    // do something
} else {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty('myProperty')) { // FAILS compilation, because response is of type 'never' here.
        // do something else
    }
}
```

The same inference actually happens with a check like: `if (response instanceof Array)`

Is it possible to do this without explicit casting?

Comment: what about `(response as any).hasOwnProperty('myProperty')`?

Comment: Actually casting does work, but it seems like this is not the best way to solve this inference? If that's the only way then I guess I'll run with it.

Comment: Got it. Another answer to your question interests me too.

Comment: What's the type of `response`?

Comment: Please share larger portion of your code. If you are getting `never type` in the else part it means your response object has array type explicitly.

Comment: Looks like your `response` is typed as `Array`, so you will never reach the `else` block, which explain why `response` has a type of `never` in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "!" symbol is maybe what's your looking for 
[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator]

```
const response:number[] =[12];


if (Array.isArray(response)) {
    // do something
} else {
    if (response!.hasOwnProperty('myProperty')) { // will not fail thank to the non-null-assertion-operator
        // do something else

    }
}
```